# RAR Each folder in directory

Tags: scripting, backup, rar

I'm new to Linux commands and spend most of my time in VB. After searching the web it's hard to find a solution in Google.

Anyway, everyday I backup my Shares folder and ends up being 183 GIG. I tried many ways of backing it up and come to the conclusion that using rar was the best option for my enviroment. So this is the command I use:

```
./rar a -v1g -m0 -ow -ag[dd-mm-yy] Shares "/shares"
```

The result I get is a lot of part files "`Shares[15-07-09].part01.rar`" which is fine.

What I really want to do now is to backup each folder within the shares directory, so I get something like:

```
Folder1[15-07-09].part01.rar
Folder2[15-07-09].part01.rar
Folder3[15-07-09].part01.rar
```

Well I hope you guys can help with a simple script that I should be able to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /shares ; find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec rar a -v1g -m0 -ow '-ag[dd-mm-yy]'  '/backupdir/{}' '{}' ';'
```

The find command searches for directories (-type d) non-recursively (-maxdepth 1) in "/shares" and executes (-exec) the rar command.  The '{}' is replaced by the name of the directory found.  I'm not sure about all your rar switches but if the command below works then the find command should do what you want:

```
rar a -v1g -m0 -ow -ag[dd-mm-yy] /backupdir/Folder1 /shares/Folder1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with.

```
cd /BackupServer/WNGLX2/ ; find /shares -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n" |xargs -i /BackupServer/WNGLX2/rar a -v1g -m0 -ow -ag[dd-mm-yy] {} /shares/{} \;
```